# Why glass is considered as an opaque body...?

Tags: optical-materials, glass

We know that the transmissivity of glass is 0 then also in general conditions it is taken as an opaque body and also in some books, it is taken as an opaque body.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. But for thermal radiation (far infrared), glass i opaque. Also in the UV.

Answer (score 1):

For any given chemical composition of what is called "glass" (and there are many different ones), each different composition will allow some wavelengths of light to pass through it while blocking other wavelengths.

For example, soda-lime glass (as commonly used in house windows) passes visible light but blocks a lot of the infrared. On the other hand, fused quartz glass passes both visible and much of the IR wavelengths, and so it is used for windows in things like wood stoves.